# Should we remove the "cars" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 4 questions tagged [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars).

We also have 2 questions tagged [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel).  One of those is also tagged [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars), and the [other](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/611/make-life-easier-for-motion-sick-dog-when-traveling) mentions cars, so should have the [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) tag if we decide to keep it.

However, do we need both [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) and [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)?  It seems to me that any question involving [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) implies travel.  Is there a sufficient distinction to merit two separate tags?

If so, is [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) what we want?  What about trucks, boats, trains, etc.?  I would prefer not to see separate tags for each of those, so if we need a tag to accomplish what [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) is trying to do, perhaps we should reconsider the name?

Answer (score 8):

I think travel works best in this case, and adding other modes of transportation tags seems somewhat superfluous, and I don't think there is enough distinction to warrant a second more specific tag.

Comment: Agreed.  I used the cars tag once (because it already existed); if I'd noticed the travel tag I would have used that instead.

Comment: I implemented the recommendations in Josh's answer (which remove the "cars" tag).

Comment: That sounds excellent :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, let's look at the four questions:

***(1) What are the risks of leaving a dog unattended in the car?***

The answer to this question (and this question itself) really applies to any vehicle; in this sense, [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) is not appropriate, but neither is [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel); [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) is fine on its own.

***(2) Long Car Trips with my Dog*** and ***(3) How can I keep my cats safe in my car?***

[travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) is much more appropriate for these, with [cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) as a synonym.

***(4) What's a suitable way to drive with a big dog in the car?***

Both [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) ([cars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) as synonym) and [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) for this, since you can have a big dog in a tight space in other vehicles.

Comment: Implemented (except that I can't create the synonym).